# Garbage collector reclaims bitmap even when there is a strong reference to it. Why?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have a Xamarin android app in which I've a bitmap with a strong reference. Inside an OnCompleteListener, I call GC.Collect() and surprisingly the GC clears the memory occupied by the bitmap. This causes an ObjectDisposedException later on in my code.

Below is the code

```
View view = (View)sender;
var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(480, 640, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
view.Post(async () =>
{
    var recognizer = TextRecognition.GetClient(Xamarin.Google.MLKit.Vision.Text.Latin.TextRecognizerOptions.DefaultOptions);
    DummyObj dumObj = new DummyObj();
    dumObj.bitmap = bitmap;
    await recognizer.Process(InputImage.FromBitmap(bitmap, 0)).AddOnCompleteListener(new GmsTaskCompleteListener<Text>(visionText =>
    {
        GC.Collect();
    },
    errorMessage =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred");
    }));
    Console.WriteLine(dumObj.bitmap.ByteCount);
    Console.WriteLine(bitmap.ByteCount);
    Console.WriteLine("Experiment Completed!");
});
```

As per my understanding of the async/await and GC, the garbage collector should not reclaim the memory of this bitmap.
The fix I have for this situation is to do a GCHandle.Alloc on the bitmap and later free it.

Anyone understands what is going on, and can help with the right fix?

**Why am I doing a GC.Collect()?**
This is just a sample. In the actual app, the ObjectDisposedException happens every once in a while and I narrowed it down to the GC reclaiming the memory. So, I am doing a GC.Collect() here to make this reproducible.

Comment: This source code is not Java and the execution environment is not a JVM, so why do you expect a java-based answer?

Comment: @Holger I've removed the Java tag. I had added the Java tag because the garbage collection of Java.Lang.Objects in Xamarin is a bit different. I was reading about garbage collection in Xamarin [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/garbage-collection)

Comment: This seems to be C#, so it might be worth adding the language tag here, even if the garbage collector in Xamarin has differences, as it’s not clear whether those differences are relevant to your problem. One question would be whether the `ObjectDisposedException` is caused by garbage collection at all. There could be an explicit invocation of `Dispose()`, for example.

Comment: GC will not dispose an object that is referenced by another object.  bitmap is not owned by another object so it gets disposed.  I would get the bit count before view.Post so you can write the size later in the code.

Comment: @jdweng I logged the ByteCount in this sample just for illustration. What I was trying to illustrate is that even though the bitmap is being used later on in the code, GC for some reason decides to collect it. This is quite confusing and is causing issues in my real code. 
In my real code, I am passing around the bitmap and working on it.

Comment: GC will not dispose as long as there is one object that references an object.  You have nothing in the code that uses the bitmap when the dispose is called so it is deleted.   You need to either link the bitmap to another object or move the dispose to a location after the bitmap is linked.

Comment: @jdweng I don't think that is the case. To validate it, I created another object called dumObj which now references the bitmap. The GC is still deleting it. I've updated the sample code to include this.

Comment: The optimizing compiler is removing unused code.  The variable dumObj is being optimized away.

Comment: @jdweng That was not the case. I had tested it; now included the usage too in the sample code.

Comment: If Guangyu Bai is correct than GC must be removing object after you posted code and must be doing so due to low memory.  Then we must ask "is the swap space configured properly"?  See : https://www.techtarget.com/searchwindowsserver/definition/swap-file-swap-space-or-pagefile